# Google Shared drive files are not accessible via google API

Tags: google-drive-shared-drive

I got files on Shared drive in Google. Also I created service account and add it as Shared drive member. In that case its permission should propagate to every folder on every files.
But when I try to go through the file structure by python I can see only some of the files (probably those which weren't edited by another user).
When I try add the service account on all files in any folder manually via web browser, then all of them appear via Google API as well.

So how can I propagate permissions to every file in folder?
And yes, I tried to wait 24h for propagation :(